# SAPGUI for Java connections.template deployment

Tags: sap

I've created a package without a payload that runs the postinstall script that essentially just copies our PlatinGUI750_7-######.jar, templates.jar, and SAPGUILandscape.xml from our server to /tmp and runs the PlatinGUI installer silently. Into the templates.jar, I have included a trustClassification.template and a settings.template

After deploying, I can view the SAPGUILandscape.xml in ~/Library/Preferences/SAP and it does have the proper  and  tags that look exactly like I would want it to, but that is not showing up as a connection when I launch SAPGUI.

I figured I probably need to include connections.template in my templates.jar so that it gets deployed during the installation, but I cannot for the life of me find a working example of that, and the SAP GUI for Java 7.50 Manual provides no clear explanation on how to configure this.

If anybody can get me posted in the right direction, it would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, RTFM.

All the necessary settings are thoroughly described in latest [PlatinGUIXXXManual file](https://www.int13h.nl:8443/_content/SAPDocuments/JavaGUI_Manual/manual.html) which is always shipped together with jar file. If you read it, you will find out that **connections.template** [is deprecated](https://www.int13h.nl:8443/_content/SAPDocuments/JavaGUI_Manual/manual.html#loio4efbd903b4354917832f260907d2f8c3) and now only **settings**, **trustClassification**, **applications**, **globs** and **externalCommands** are in use.

Secondly, check that all your config files/templates have valid syntax. The setting that is of interest to us is `@SAPUILANDSCAPE=` which refers to location of SAPUILandscape.xml (former **connections**), the syntax of this file **fully** resembles Windows file (in early versions of JavaGUI they were different) so to check the validity you can just install SAPGUI for Windows and copy the file from there.

Here is the sample configurations provided you wanna setup connection to **US1**, **US2** and **US3** SAP systems.

**trustClassification.template**

```
############################################################
#
# file    : /home/sapp/.SAPGUI/trustClassification
# created : 28.02.2019 06:18:44 EET
# encoding: UTF-8
#
############################################################
US1:Level4
US2:Level5
US3@/H/vpn.server.com:Level4
```

**SAPUILandscape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Landscape version="1" updated="2019-02-28T04:35:42Z" origin="file:/home/sapper/.SAPGUI/SAPGUILandscape.xml" generator="SAP GUI for Java 7.50 rev 5">
   <Workspaces default="69213476-467d-4583-8cfa-36bca63d391e">
      <Workspace expanded="1" name="Local" uuid="69213476-467d-4583-8cfa-36bca63d391e">
         <Item uuid="ddbb7423-a6b9-456d-a616-19310a321433" serviceid="f0375479-7d8d-48bd-83aa-a272495d28a4" />
         <Item uuid="fe41b832-effe-4110-b850-ee5e5c177820" serviceid="2f156590-27ec-4b62-a2da-9adecdcd2961" />
         <Item uuid="0a7e6630-45a3-45fd-b5c3-ef1fc226ed66" serviceid="95ce37c2-18f4-4549-b2b4-002c2b5657bd" />
      </Workspace>
   </Workspaces>
   <Services>
      <Service uuid="f0375479-7d8d-48bd-83aa-a272495d28a4" name="US1" server="sapserver1.com:3200" sncop="-1" mode="1" systemid="US1" msid="" type="SAPGUI" sapcpg="1100" dcpg="2" />
      <Service uuid="2f156590-27ec-4b62-a2da-9adecdcd2961" name="US2" server="sapserver2.com:3204" sncop="-1" mode="1" systemid="US2" msid="" type="SAPGUI" sapcpg="1100" dcpg="2" />
      <Service uuid="95ce37c2-18f4-4549-b2b4-002c2b5657bd" name="US3" routerid="995bee2e-28a9-41fb-aec2-7cfe755a2a83" server="sapserver3.com:3207" sncop="-1" mode="1" systemid="US3" msid="" type="SAPGUI" sapcpg="1100" dcpg="2" />
   </Services>
   <Routers>
      <Router router="/H/vpn.server.com" name="/H/vpn.server.com" uuid="995bee2e-28a9-41fb-aec2-7cfe755a2a83" description="/H/vpn.server.com" />
   </Routers>
   <Messageservers />
</Landscape>
```

**settings.template**

```
############################################################
#
# file    : /home/sapper/.SAPGUI/settings
# created : 28.02.2019 06:18:44 EET
# encoding: UTF-8
#
############################################################
@INCLUDE = "/home/sapper/.SAPGUI/settings/guiconfig.ini" <- optional
@SAPUILANDSCAPE = "/home/sapper/.SAPGUI/settings/SAPUILandscape.xml"
@logonFrame_2_X = "515"
@logonFrame_2_Y = "211"
@logonFrame_2_Width = "755"
@GLF_combidivider = "150"
@logonFrame_2_Height = "665"
@LSSelection = "69213476-467d-4583-8cfa-36bca63d391e:3a0e9a24-d62b-4299-9ef6-c0d7a5b26873"
```

As I highlighted above, `@INCLUDE` directive is optional and can be omitted. All paths here are specified for Linux version, just correct to Mac paths and that's it. I suppose you install for Mac as I see from your post.

Then put all these files into single folder and create **templates.jar** like that:

```
jar -cf /Users/username/Downloads/templates.jar /Users/username/settings.template /Users/username/trustClassification.template
```

The final thing you should do is to include your templates.jar into installer and rebuild the installer. Use this manual for reference

[https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2018/10/11/building-an-sap-gui-installer-for-macos](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2018/10/11/building-an-sap-gui-installer-for-macos/)